# Update table A when row inserted in table B with multi select column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables like so:

```
Visitors     ID|Name|Visit_from|To|image 
Visitor_log  ID|Name|Visit_from|To|requestor
```

When I insert a record into `Visitor_log` the dates are updated in the visitors table. I have this working when 1 visitor is requested. The problem is `Visitor_log.Visitor` field is a multi-select field so the code only works for one visitor:

```
sub row_inserted (rsold, rsnew)

ew_execute ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('" & rsnew("To Visit On") & "'), 
[To] = ('" & rsnew("To") & "') 
WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] = ('" & rsnew("Visitor") & "');")
```

The where clause becomes:

```
WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] = (Visitor A)
```

But when multiple visitors are selected it becomes:

```
WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] = (Visitor A, Visitor B, Visitor C)
```

There are no visitors called `Visitor A, Visitor B, Visitor C` as one name in the visitors table so the SQL query fails.

I've been stuck on this a while now any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: I have set the query to `response.write` to show what the SQL is doing...

`sql: UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('10/10/2014'), [To] = ('10/10/2014') WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] = ('Mark M, Paul P');`

Comment: I think you might need to change `=` to `IN` in your `WHERE` criteria.  What exactly does `rsnew("Visitor")` return?  I would think you'd need single quotes around each visitor for either options to work though.

Comment: Hi, i have tried IN but no joy, again it does work for 1 visitor not more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED!

Here is the complete working answer:

`Dim sql

sql = ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('" & rsnew("To Visit On") & "'), [To] = ('" & rsnew("To") & "') WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] IN ('" & replace(rsnew("Visitor"),", ","','") & "');")

Call ew_Execute(sql)`

This was smalarons answer with a slight edit to the spacing in the replace statment.

Thanks to all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing your update, I think your problem lies in the quotes. Each distinct values should be quoted and you should use the IN operator.
So your query should look like that :

```
UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('10/10/2014'), [To] = ('10/10/2014')
WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] IN ('Mark M', 'Paul P');
```

So assuming that rsnew("visitor") is a string of values separated by comas and that your language is Vbscript you could do something like this

```
ew_execute ("UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('" & rsnew("To Visit On") & "'), 
[To] = ('" & rsnew("To") & "') 
WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] IN ('" & replace(rsnew("Visitor"),",","','") & "');")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will test it out now and let you know, thanks.

Comment: make sur you use the IN operator instead of `=`. I failed to change it myself when I pasted you code. It's corrected now.

Comment: Thanks for the info i will retry.

Comment: I have re-tried the above code with the `IN` operator. Progress has been made. The dates do update the for the first visitor when multiple visitors are selected, the dates for the second visitor remain blank, also it still works when 1 visitor is selected.

Comment: Hi I have been unable to get this to work so used `Response.Write "sql: " & sql & "<br>" ' ***
Response.End ' *** ` to see what was returned `sql: UPDATE [Visitors] SET [To Visit On] = ('14/10/2014'), [To] = ('14/10/2014') WHERE [Visitors].[Visitor(s) Name] IN ('AAA',' BBB');` This looks perfect it should work, any ideas.

Comment: I found the issue, there is a space after the second comma `IN ('AAA',' BBB');` If i can close this space it will work. I just need to edit this bit `('" & replace(rsnew("Visitor"),",","','") & "');")` If anyone knows how please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define a trigger on the visitor_log table to update the visitor table.
In Mysql this would be something like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER visitor_log_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON visitor_log
FOR EACH ROW 
   UPDATE visitor SET visitor.to = NEW.to, visitor.visit_from = NEW.visit_from
   WHERE visitor.name=NEW.name;
```

Comment: Hi, having re-read this answer I already have a trigger.. `Sub Row_inserted (rsold, rsnew)` this is a row inserted event and everything after the 'ew_execute' triggers when a new row has been inserted in the visitor_log table. The problem is with the `WHERE` clause. My database is trying to find a visitor called `(vis1,vis2,vis3)` when 1 visitor is selected it works as the databse see's `(Vis1)` and can match that up with a name from the `Visitors` table.